# What should I put as SecurityGroup for CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to allow CodeBuild to run my database migrations. I am configuring my CodeBuild project to be in the VPC and subnet of my RDS. But what do I put for security group? Is this security group to allow/deny access to my CodeBuild? Or should I understand it as the security group I want my CodeBuild to access?

Answer (score -2):

Quote from CodeBuild doc:
"For Security Groups, choose the security groups that AWS CodeBuild uses to allow access to resources in the VPCs."

Learn more about using VPC with CodeBuild: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html

Comment: I read that but didn't understand it. Am I right to say I should select the DB security group if I want to allow access to DB?

Comment: yes, you should select a security group allows access to your DB, if your build needs to access the DB from your VPC.